# How can I remove comma between first and last names in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have to remove the comma between the first and last names of "name" in an array called "players" using .map() and .split().

This is the array I'm given:

```
const players = [
  { name: 'Modrić, Luka', year: 1985 },
  { name: 'Christian, Eriksen', year: 1992 },
  { name: 'Griezmann, Antoine', year: 1991 },
  { name: 'Achraf, Hakimi', year: 1998 },
  { name: 'Martínez, Lautaro', year: 1997 }
];
```

This is the code I have so far, to get name out of the array using .map():

```
const mapped = players.map(({ name }) => {
  return name;
})
console.log(mapped);
```

Which logs this in the console:

```
[
  'Modrić, Luka',
  'Christian, Eriksen',
  'Griezmann, Antoine',
  'Achraf, Hakimi',
  'Martínez, Lautaro'
]
```

Now how do I use .split() to remove the the commas between the first and last name? Im lost :(

Thanks for any help! :)

I tried using .map to get each name from the players array. Then I tried using .split() to no avail :(

Comment: you can use regexp to remove the comma instead. before returning the name in your map function do that first.

Comment: Split splits a string into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String#replace`.

```js
const players = [
  { name: 'Modrić, Luka', year: 1985 },
  { name: 'Christian, Eriksen', year: 1992 },
  { name: 'Griezmann, Antoine', year: 1991 },
  { name: 'Achraf, Hakimi', year: 1998 },
  { name: 'Martínez, Lautaro', year: 1997 }
];
let res = players.map(({name}) => name.replace(',', ''));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This looks great but I (have) to use .split() to do this. It's a small school assignment :(

Comment: @Gustuckit You could use `name.split(',').join('')` then

Answer (score 1):

```js
const players = [
  { name: 'Modrić, Luka', year: 1985 },
  { name: 'Christian, Eriksen', year: 1992 },
  { name: 'Griezmann, Antoine', year: 1991 },
  { name: 'Achraf, Hakimi', year: 1998 },
  { name: 'Martínez, Lautaro', year: 1997 }
];

// use `split` to split
console.log(players.map(player => player.name.split(', ')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use split, which then you would have to use join to change it back to a string:

```
  { name: 'Modrić, Luka', year: 1985 },
  { name: 'Christian, Eriksen', year: 1992 },
  { name: 'Griezmann, Antoine', year: 1991 },
  { name: 'Achraf, Hakimi', year: 1998 },
  { name: 'Martínez, Lautaro', year: 1997 }
];

const mapped = players.map(({ name }) => {
  let splitName = name.split(',');
  return splitName.join('')
})
console.log(mapped);
```

But I think this would be better:

```
  { name: 'Modrić, Luka', year: 1985 },
  { name: 'Christian, Eriksen', year: 1992 },
  { name: 'Griezmann, Antoine', year: 1991 },
  { name: 'Achraf, Hakimi', year: 1998 },
  { name: 'Martínez, Lautaro', year: 1997 }
];

const mapped = players.map(({ name }) => {
  return name.replace(',', '')
})
console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Thanks for showing these 2 options! So .replace is like .split and .join combined in this case? :)

Comment: Not really, but you get the same result in this situation.  the .split method splits a string into an array, and depending on the argument you pass, that is where it splits it. .join turns the array back into a string. replace is more like searching a string for the first argument, in this case the comma, and replacing it with the second argument, the empty string.